# how to pass access token from local storage in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idAYC.png)

Here i have screen shot of my local storage. how can i fetch access token from there pass as headers in below action page. please provide any solution for this. how we can fetch token from local storage using react redux and display in action page.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const upiAction = {
    upi,


};
function upi(user) {
return (dispatch) => {
        var data = {
            upiId: user.upiId,
            accountNumber: user.accountNumber,
        };

        axios
            .post('http://localhost:9091/upiidcreation', data,


        )
            .then((res) => {

                console.log("res", (res));

                const { data } = res;
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.responseDesc));

                // window.location.pathname = "./homes";
                if (data.responseCode === "00") {
                    window.location.pathname = "./home"
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {

                dispatch(setUserUpiError(err, true));
                alert("Please Check With details");

            });


    };
}

export function setUserUpi(showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_UPI_SUCCESS',
        showError: showError,

    };
}


export function setUserUpiError(error, showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_UPI_ERROR',
        error: error,
        showError: showError,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to fetch the token and send it as header in the api request you can do this

```
let storageValue =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
```

storageValue object will have the whole thing that you've stored in localStorage .

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:9091/upiidcreation', data, {
    headers: {
     token : storageValue?.data?.accessToken
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get localStorage Object like this

let localStorageObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

Then You can use it that object to get access token like this:
**localStorageObject?.data?.accessToken**